# Adding UIButton To UITableView Programmatically Wrong Spot

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to get a UIButton added to a TableView, where it sits in the bottom right corner of the table view, 20 from the right edge, and 20 from the bottom.  However, it ends up sticking the button at the top left edge.  What am I doing wrong?

```
UIButton *goToTop = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [goToTop setImage:redGo forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [goToTop addTarget:self action:@selector(beginCampaign) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [goToTop setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [goToTop.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
    [self.tableView addSubview:goToTop];

    goToTop.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    /* Leading space to superview */
    NSLayoutConstraint *leftButtonXConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                 constraintWithItem:goToTop attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.tableView attribute:
                                                 NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:20];
    /* Top space to superview Y*/
    NSLayoutConstraint *leftButtonYConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                 constraintWithItem:goToTop attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.tableView attribute:
                                                 NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:20];
    /* Fixed width */
    NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:goToTop
                                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                          toItem:nil
                                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                      multiplier:1.0
                                                                        constant:60];
    /* Fixed Height */
    NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:goToTop
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:nil
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                       multiplier:1.0
                                                                         constant:60];
    /* 4. Add the constraints to button's superview*/
    [self.tableView addConstraints:@[leftButtonXConstraint, leftButtonYConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint]];
```

Here is how I would like it:

[image]

Here is how it appears:

[image]

Comment: Do you want the button inside the tableview or outside the tableview? Are you using a view controller or a tableviewcontroller?  You should use leading and trailing rather than left/right attributes

Comment: @Paulw11 I want the button IN the TableView, the tableview is inside a navigationController

Comment: Then you should use leading=leading and bottom=bottom, not left=right and top=bottom. Your view controller may be in a navigation controller, but it is a direct UIViewController subclass or a UITableViewController subclass?  I.e.  What is the root view? A uiview or the tableview?

Comment: @Paulw11 The complete hierarchy of the app is this.  Root view is a tabBarController, the view in question starts with a NavigationController, with a ViewController in it that loads from its own nib, which is a TableViewController.

Comment: I added some pics to demonstrate

Comment: I would suggest you use a view controller containing a tableview rather than a tableviewcontroller. Then you can add the button to the root view rather than the tableview. You may also need to reconsider your constraints since your tableview is under the top and bottom bars.  Also you should consider using a storyboard rather than nib files. You can easily lay all,of this out in a storyboard with no code

Comment: Using frame to layout, did the button appear?

Comment: @Chwang I can manually set the frame to get the button to where I want it, but on other devices it does not end up where I want it of course

Comment: @Paulw this is how it has to be so helping me constrain it to bottom right instead of having me redesign everything would be great.

Comment: Have you tried bottom = bottom & trailing = trailing.  As you have it now, it will be trying to put the button outside the tablview.  Also, you need to set the width & height constraints on the button, not on the tableview.  I am sure you must be getting constraints warnings in your console

Comment: @Paulw11 I have the height and width constraints already set on the button not the tableview.  I have tried nearly every combination, and it always leaves it at the top left.

Comment: @Paulw11 I set bottom=bottom and trailing=trailing and set each constant to about 300 and it has it about that distance from leading and top.

Comment: You have set the width and height on the tableview because you have added the width and height constraints to the buttons superview, not the button itself.

Comment: I just tested this.  You can't add subviews to a UITableView.  You will need to use a view controller and add the tableview to it and then you can add the button to the root view and set its constraints relative to the tableview

Answer (score 0):

You have set your constraints to the top left of the table view not the bottom right.
Change this:

```
/* Leading space to superview */
NSLayoutConstraint *leftButtonXConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                             constraintWithItem:goToTop attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.tableView attribute:
                                             NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:20];
/* Top space to superview Y*/
NSLayoutConstraint *leftButtonYConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                             constraintWithItem:goToTop attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.tableView attribute:
                                             NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:20];
```

To this:

```
/* Leading space to superview */
NSLayoutConstraint *leftButtonXConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                             constraintWithItem:goToTop attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.tableView attribute:
                                             NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:20];
/* Top space to superview Y*/
NSLayoutConstraint *leftButtonYConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                             constraintWithItem:goToTop attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.tableView attribute:
                                             NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:20];
```